# ShopifyAPI Gem calculate refunds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am using the `shopify_api` gem for an app I am making. The refund process is handled entirely in app and I am only needing to update the order on Shopify as being refunded. I don't need Shopify to do anything other than register the payment status change. I have read that I need to first use `Refund.calculate` in the gem to get a transaction parent id before actually making the request to the refund endpoint. My problem is, while reading the docs, I can not decipher how to format the arguments for the `.calculate` request.  Here is the method in question from the gem.

```
module ShopifyAPI
  class Refund < Base
    init_prefix :order

    def self.calculate(*args)
      options = { :refund => args[0] }
      params = {}
      params = args[1][:params] if args[1] && args[1][:params]

      resource = post(:calculate, params, options.to_json)
      instantiate_record(format.decode(resource.body), {})
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried `Refund.calculate({shipping: { full_refund: true }, currency: 'EUR', refund_line_items: [{line_item_id: 12344556, quantity: 1}, restock: true]}, params: {order_id: 23453245})` I have also tried `restock_type: 'restock'` I keep getting 406 or 422 errors.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Hitting the same wall

Comment: I have not, I'm sorry :(. I had to table this feature for now. This was more of a plan ahead thing for my current project in case the client wanted full sync between the app and shopify. I'll actually put a todo in my project to update this question if/when I figure this out

Comment: Thanks for responding - I'll update you if come across a solution

Answer (score 2):

I think you had your `refund_line_items` formatted incorrectly. Here is what I used:

```
ShopifyAPI::Refund.calculate({
  refund_line_items: order.line_items.map { |li|
    {
      line_item_id: li.id,
      quantity: li.quantity,
      restock_type: 'cancel',
    }
  },
  shipping: { full_refund: true },
}, {
  params: { order_id: order.id },
})
```